# Redis detect when a key's value is changed

Tags: redis

Without using keyspace notifications, pub/sub and streams, is there a way to detect/listen to a key's value being changed (or a key being added to a hashmap) in Redis?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use a Redis module? RedisGears will do this.

Comment: I am not sure yet, will check, thanks!